# C# Base Class for tracking changes ADO.NET

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

I'm using Entity Framework in my application with ChangeTracking Entities so I can have an Audit Log in my database for every Add, Modification, Delete (ColumnName, OriginalValue, NewValue, etc).

There are some functions that I'm not going to use Entity Framework because is very slow, for example bulk insert / update and other scenarios, instead I will user ADO.NET with Stored Procedures.

In order to keep tracking changes on both Entity Framework and ADO.NET I was thinking on use a Base Class for custom classes that will be populated from DataReaders and will need to track changes on those classes so I came up with:

```
public class NotifyPropertyChangeObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Track changes or not.
        /// If we're working with DTOs and we fill up the DTO in the DAL we should not be tracking changes.
        /// </summary>
        private bool trackChanges = false;

        /// <summary>
        /// Changes to the object
        /// </summary>
        public List<TrackChange> Changes { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Is the object dirty or not?
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsDirty
        {
            get { return Changes.Count > 0; }
            set { ; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Event required for INotifyPropertyChanged
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// This constructor will initialize the change tracking
        /// </summary>
        public NotifyPropertyChangeObject()
        {
            // Change tracking default
            trackChanges = true;

            // New change tracking dictionary
            Changes = new List<TrackChange>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Reset the object to non-dirty
        /// </summary>
        public void Reset()
        {
            Changes.Clear();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Start tracking changes
        /// </summary>
        public void StartTracking()
        {
            trackChanges = true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stop tracking changes
        /// </summary>
        public void StopTracking()
        {
            trackChanges = false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Change the property if required and throw event
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="variable"></param>
        /// <param name="property"></param>
        /// <param name="value"></param>
        public void ApplyPropertyChange<T, F>(ref F field, Expression<Func<T, object>> property, F value)
        {
            // Only do this if the value changes
            if (field == null || !field.Equals(value))
            {
                // Get the property
                var propertyExpression = GetMemberExpression(property);
                if (propertyExpression == null)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("You must specify a property");

                // Property name
                string propertyName = propertyExpression.Member.Name;


                // If change tracking is enabled, we can track the changes...
                if (trackChanges)
                {
                    // Change tracking

                    var track = Changes.Where(c => c.Name == propertyName).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (track == null)
                    {
                        track = new TrackChange();
                        track.Name = propertyName;
                        track.Original = field;
                        track.Value = value;
                        Changes.Add(track);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        track.Name = propertyName;
                        track.Original = field;
                        track.Value = value;
                    }

                    //Changes[propertyName] = value;

                    // Notify change
                    NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName);
                }

                // Set the value
                field = value;

            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get member expression
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="expression"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public MemberExpression GetMemberExpression<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
        {
            // Default expression
            MemberExpression memberExpression = null;

            // Convert
            if (expression.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
            {
                var body = (UnaryExpression)expression.Body;
                memberExpression = body.Operand as MemberExpression;
            }
            // Member access
            else if (expression.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
            {
                memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
            }

            // Not a member access
            if (memberExpression == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("Not a member access", "expression");

            // Return the member expression
            return memberExpression;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The property has changed
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Convert the changes to an XML string
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string ChangesToXml()
        {
            // Prepare base objects
            XDeclaration declaration = new XDeclaration("1.0", Encoding.UTF8.HeaderName, String.Empty);
            XElement root = new XElement("Changes");

            // Create document
            XDocument document = new XDocument(declaration, root);

            // Add changes to the document
            // TODO: If it's an object, maybe do some other things
            //foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> change in Changes)
            //    root.Add(new XElement(change.Key, change.Value));

            // Get the XML
            return document.Document.ToString();
        }
    }

public class TrackChange
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public object Original { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }
```

That way I can keep my Audit Log functionality on both Data Context.

When saving data using ADO.NET I will have a function that will convert my **Changes** into Stored Procedures parameters so I can save into my AuditLog table.

Does anyone know if this is a good alternative?